# Symfony 4 Vue js specific component

Tags: symfony4

> Hello , Im using symfony 4 and i would use vue js for a chat module .
> How could vue js would be loaded only for the ChatController not for  the whole application ?

Answer (score 0):

A broad answer for an pretty broad question:

The most basic way to do this would be to get Vue through a CDN and create a twig template for this page as you normally would with inside the body a div with the id="#app". (example: https://techformist.com/use-vue-from-url-simple-app/). This keeps the concerns for the chat in one place and does not require to change the application in term of node modules loaded.

When working with webpack encore you could create an assets folder for this specific controller which initiates Vue. https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/split-chunks.html (splitting js modules per page) and for enabling Vue in symfony checkout https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/vuejs.html

If you really want to get to know how to use Vue with Symfony checkout:
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/vue which explains everything in detail step by step.